# Creating a combination of dummy variables into a single variable in a logistic regression model in R

Tags: r, combinations, logistic-regression, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I need to create possible combinations of 3 dummy variables into one categorical variable in a logistic regression using R.
I made the combination manually just like the following:

| new_variable_code | variable_1 | variable_2 | variable_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I excluded the other two options (0 0 1) and (1 0 1) because I do not need them, they are not represented by the data.
I then used new_variable_code as a factor in the logistic regression along with other predictors.

My question is: Is there is any automated way to create the same new_variable_code? or even another econometric technique to encode the 3 dummy variables into 1 categorical variable inside a logistic regression model?

My objective: To understand which variable combination has the highest odds ratio on the outcome variable (along with other predictors explained in the same model).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pmap_dbl` in the following way to recode your dummy variables to a 1-6 scale:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Reproducing your data
df1 <- tibble(
  variable_1 = c(0,0,0,1,1,1),
  variable_2 = c(0,1,1,0,1,1),
  variable_3 = c(0,0,1,0,0,1)
)

factorlevels <- c("000","010","011","100","110","111")

df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(
    new_variable_code = pmap_dbl(list(variable_1, variable_2, variable_3),
                                 ~ which(paste0(..1, ..2, ..3) == factorlevels))
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  variable_1 variable_2 variable_3 new_variable_code
       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>             <dbl>
1          0          0          0                 1
2          0          1          0                 2
3          0          1          1                 3
4          1          0          0                 4
5          1          1          0                 5
6          1          1          1                 6
```

Comment: Thank you for writing the code. I was looking whether there is an automated way to do so. Like a mathematical function that creates the new combination variable without telling R the steps.

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a variable with paste using sep="." and make it a factor:

```
 newvar <- factor( paste(variable_1,    variable_2, variable_3, sep="."))
```

I don't think it would be a good idea to then make it a sequential vlaue, it's already an integer with levels, since that's how factors get created.